# How to add "Safe Remove" option to context menu with srm? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, secure-erase

I want to secure delete files from context menu, same as like [here for Linux Mint KDE 18.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374606/how-to-add-shred-to-kde-context-menu-for-safe-deletion-of-file-folder/59374607#59374607) but with Ubuntu 20.04 and nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo apt-get install secure-delete`
2. Make file `Secure delete` here: `/home/$USER/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`

2.1. Add code to file `Secure delete`:

```
#!/bin/sh
srm -llrv "$@"
```

3. Give execution permission: `chmod +x "/home/$USER/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Secure delete"`
4. Enjoy, using right click on files/folders.

[image]